# fetching data from multiple tables, mssql, php, apache

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, apache

Looking to create my own report/stats page for our call center...

```
Table 1 (agent)
CODE....NAME
AXA     apple bottom
AXB     apple pear

Table 2 (stat)
AGENT.....CAMPAIGN....CALLS....PITCHES.....TALKTIME......dialdate 
AXA       CCC         5        2           90(sec)       2-2-2013
AXA       DDD         5        2           20(sec)       2-2-2013 
AXB       DDD         1        1           20(Sec)       2-2-2013

Table 3 (result_CCC)
AGENTID.....lcdate......samount.....upamt......termcd
AXA         2-2-2013    $10         $5         SA

Table 4 (result_DDD)
AGENTID.....lcdate......samount.....upamt......termcd
AXA         2-2-2013    $0          $0         BN
AXB         2-2-2013    $0          $0         NI
```

I want to display my table as follow

```
Agent Name  ---  Calls ---- Pitches --- talktime --- samount --- upamt
Apple Bottom     10         4           110(sec)     $10         $5
```

but calls has to be a SUM of all calls made that day (not just by campaign and not tied to the TERMCD)
but pitches has to be a SUM of all pitches made that day (not just by campaign and not tied to the TERMCD)
but talktime has to be a SUM of all talktime made that day (not just by campaign and not tied to the TERMCD)
samount has to be a SUM of all termcd = SA only for that day
upamt has to be a SUM of all termcd = SA only for that day

Here is the string i'm using now, which is still missing a few items:

```
SELECT agent.name, stats.agent, SUM(stats.calls) AS sumcalls, SUM(stats.pitches) AS     sumpitches, SUM(stats.talktime) AS sumtalktime, SUM(stats.wrapuptime) as sumwrapuptime, SUM(stats.dialtime) as sumdialtime, (SUM(stats.wrapuptime) + SUM(stats.talktime) + sum(stats.dialtime)) as sumtotal
FROM dbo.stats 
     INNER JOIN dbo.agent ON agent.code = stats.agent
WHERE (stats.agent !='' and stats.dialdate = '".($_GET['datetime'])."') and (stats.campaign = '".($_GET['camp_select'])."' or stats.campaign = '')
GROUP BY agent.name, stats.agent
ORDER BY SUM(stats.talktime) ASC";
```

My concern with this is, that when I start to add WHERE termcd = 'SA', then my calls, pitches, talktime, etc.... will also change, but those columns need not be affected by the TERMCD = 'SA' function.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: sorry, can't figure out how to format my tables to look better and readable.

Comment: Can you create an example of your tabs here: http://sqlfiddle.com/. It will be easier to play with the query then. It looks as though you need sub selects though. So `(select something from table where 1=1) as something`.

Comment: Thanks webnoob...have researched subselects already, not sure I understand them 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You need a conditional summation:

```
select . . .
       sum(case when termcd = 'SA' then samount end) as sa,
       sum(case when termcd = 'SA' then upamount end) as up
. . .
```

That is, don't filter by the criteria in the `where` clause.  Just put the logic in as a conditional sum.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, will try this